# Low NTFS performance, software issue or inherent to the hardware?

Tags: ntfs

I am using the latest stable Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) with a Pi 4. One thing I have found is that its NTFS write speed is very slow. On the same disk, the writing speed on an NTFS partition was about 30 MB/S, and the writing speed on an EXT4 partition was over 100MB/s.

Is this a software issue or a hardware limitation? I have not used a desktop Linux on a non-x86 computer before, and on other desktop Linux (running on a regular PC) the NTFS performance was normal (not that slow for me to notice the difference from Windows). Why is it so slow on a Pi 4? Is this due to the Raspberry Pi OS and if I use other Linux distributions, it gets better? I have only one SD card for now, so I cannot easily test it. Or is this the limitation of an ARM processor and cannot be improved?

Comment: I think it’s a similar problem to my very slow FAT32 issue. My Pi was hosting a shared drive that was shared between Macs and Linux (with an odd PC in the mix). From what I could tell it seems that the user space drivers are very slow when compared to the kernel based ext2/3/4 drivers.  I solved my issue by buying a two drive JBOD box for the Mac, adding ‘ext’ drivers on the Mac and reformatting the Pi drive to ext4.  This sorted my speed issue.

Comment: @Andyroo So, it is basically a software issue, and if there were a kernel-based NTFS driver, it would not be that slow on the same hardware?

Comment: Do not know - I was working with Carbon Copy Pro (for remote transfer) on a Mac when I spotted it and as we identified where the issue was I worked around it.  My understanding is that only basic sata/scsi and ext2/3/4 are built in as that boots Linux - every other format is user space (USB may built in be for ‘live’ distros come to think).  Never tried on an x86 box as they are all ext4 currently - maybe ask the same on the general Linux site?

Comment: NTFS is closed source and documentation of it isn't public and not available. The NTFS drivers on Linux are made only by reverse engineering and it is known that is has bad performance compared to Microsofts implementation.

Comment: @Ingo Since Microsoft now "loves Linux", I wonder why they at least gave the protocol specification of NTFS to the Linux. If more operating systems use NTFS, isn't it good for Microsoft?